# Issue with Datagridviewcheckboxcolumn in CellContentClick event (VB Net)

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have the following simple problem but I can´t find how to fix it. I have a DatagridviewCheckboxColumn and when I check one of its checkbox I want it do an action for each checkbox checked in that column and works but not with the last checkbox. This is my snippet:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = True Then
                    'SOME ACTION
                End If
            Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anybody tell me why this don´t work with the last checked checkbox?

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure about the issue, but typically the problem is that the row's changes haven't been committed, so try adding an EndEdit method into your routine:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
  If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    '...
```